# pureComputed and observableArray not being hit with conditional variable

Tags: knockout.js

Is there anyway for knockout.js to reevaulate the `ConflicingGames` when `self.Matchup` is not null.  `self.Matchup` isnt an observable and is NULL initially.

```
self.Conflict = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            return self.Matchup ? self.Matchup.ConflictingGames.length > 0 : false;
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You check seems to not be `ko` valid since you are not actually checking if the observable array length is `> 0`. Probably should be:

```
self.Conflict = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return self.Matchup ? self.Matchup.ConflictingGames().length > 0 : false;
});
```

And if you want to be defensive with `ko` checks you should use `ko.isObservable`.

Also since you are using `pureComputed` it does not matter what happens before the observable is invoked ... as long as at the time of the call the enclosed observables exist. Not the case with `computed` observables which evaluate right away.

Here is a simple example:

```js
var vm = {
  array: null
};

vm.array = ko.observableArray([150]);

vm.status = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return this.array().length > 0 ? "positive foo" : "foo";
}, vm);

vm.fooStatus = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  return this.array.length > 0 ? "positive foo" : "foo";
}, vm);

console.log(vm.status())
console.log(vm.fooStatus())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did that but the problem is the observable never gets executed again because self.Matchup is not an observable

Comment: The only way to trigger computed observables is via an observable which they wrap changing or via `valueHasMutated()` in the `computed` and not `pureComputed` scenario.

Answer (score 0):

### How dependencies are created

Knockout's computed determines its dependencies whenever it evaluates. Take this example:

```
const a = ko.observable("a");
const b = ko.observable("b");

const takeA = ko.observable(true);

const aOrB = ko.pureComputed(
  () => takeA() ? a() : b()
);
```

The computed value `aOrB` has **2** dependencies:

1. On `takeA`
2. On `a`

Even though `b` appears in the function body, it is never evaluated and therefore isn't a dependency. If we were to do:

```
takeA(false)
```

The dependencies of `aOrB` would change to:

1. On `takeA`
2. On `b`

### What this means to your code in specific

Looking at this function:

```
self.Matchup ? self.Matchup.ConflictingGames().length > 0 : false
```

we quickly see that **0** dependencies will be created whenever `Matchup` is `null` (or any other falsey value). **There is no way for knockout to ever create a dependency; as far as knockout is concerned this computed is just a `const`**.

### Fixes

The "simple" solution is to make `Matchup` an observable value in your model. E.g., something like:

```
self.Matchup = ko.observable(data.Matchup);
self.Conflict = ko.pureComputed(() =>
  self.Matchup()
    ? self.Matchup().ConflictingGames().length > 0 
    : false
);
```

The only acceptable alternative I can think of if you don't want to change the property's type, is something like:

```
self.Conflict = ko.pureComputed(() =>
  self.matchupInitialized() && self.Matchup 
    ? self.Matchup.ConflictingGames().length > 0 
    : false
);

self.matchupInitialized = ko.observable(false);
self.Matchup = null;

self.setMatchup = function(v) {
  self.Matchup = v;
  self.matchupInitialized(true);
};
```

Still feels like a hack though, and will only allow you to set a `Matchup` *once*, when switching from true to false.